# Azure Table Storage: Efficient way to query multiple PK-RK pairs

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am doing a query with this filter:
 ***(PartitionKey eq 'A' or PartionKey eq 'B' or ...) and RowKey eq 'RK'***

I realized that this kind of query with 20 to 100 PKs is taking 3 to 5 seconds. The total quantity of items on the table is not much (more or less 1 million)

I think is doing a partial scan query. I assumed that it would do several puntual queries, but it seems is not the case.

My other option is do independent parallel queries and then merge the results.

- Is this a good option for 100 items?
- I will not have problems with the network connections? (I increase them with ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit)

**Note**: Not all the pair PK/RK will retrieve a record.

Answer (score 0):

> My other option is do independent parallel queries and then merge the results.

It will save the query time on Azure Storage, but it will spend more time on query request and result response. I have a table with 160K entities. I wrote two sample code to test the total times of query the entities from one query and multi queries. Here are my test result.

[image]

Following are my sample code.

Query entities from one query.

```
int entitesCount = 20;
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> customerQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();
string filter = "(";
for (int i = 0; i < entitesCount; i++)
{
    filter = filter + "PartitionKey eq '" + i + "'";
    if (i < entitesCount - 1)
    {
        filter = filter + " or ";
    }
}
filter = filter + ") and RowKey eq '42'";
customerQuery.FilterString = filter;

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

var customers = table.ExecuteQuery(customerQuery);
Console.WriteLine(customers.Count().ToString());

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

Query entities from parallel multi queries.

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;

Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

int entitesCount = 20;
List<CustomerEntity> customers = new List<CustomerEntity>();
var result = Parallel.For(0, entitesCount, new Action<int>(i =>
{
    TableQuery<CustomerEntity> customerQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();
    customerQuery.FilterString = "PartitionKey eq '" + i.ToString() + "' and RowKey eq '88'";

    var cs = table.ExecuteQuery(customerQuery);
    foreach (var c in cs)
    {
        customers.Add(c);
    }
}));
while (!result.IsCompleted) { }

Console.WriteLine(customers.Count.ToString());
stopWatch.Stop();

TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

> Azure Table Storage: Efficient way to query multiple PK-RK pairs

I suggest you test it on your side and determine which way is a good one.

Comment: Thanks Amor for your answer. I will do a test like you propose.

Comment: After some testings I concluded that in my particular case making paralel queries grouping 30 items in the IN statement was the most performant.

Comment: Decreasing or increasing the IN items will increasse the total time needed to get the result

Comment: Additionally I found that sorting the items before grouping improved the performance too.